# How to rename a variable using Z3?

Tags: z3

given an expression x'=x+1, I wish to rename x' to y. How to do using z3?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of API functions that let you modify terms and substitute new subterms for old ones. They are described under the Modifiers section that contain the modifiers Z3_update_term, z3_substitute, and Z3_substitute_vars (there is also Z3_translate to port terms between two contexts).
Here is the link:

```
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#gaa7497c70a827db2d61ba98889fe657b5
```

You can also traverse terms directly and write utilities to modify terms. 
The display_ast example shows the main cases for recursively traversing terms:

```
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi__ex.html#ga807b5fe0e26acdec09e52a77318208d0
```

Comment: Thanks, however, is there any C# api functions that I can use for modifying terms, substituting new subterms for old ones?

Comment: Yes, the corresponding function in C# is called Substitute and is found in the Expr class. There is also Expr.Update and Expr.Translate, etc.

Comment: You probably saved 5 days of my life, thanks. The problem with the c++ APIs is that there isn't a comprehensive tutorial, except for an `example.cpp' file in the source, and looking at the documentation is very cumbersome. Do you know a good source to learn it?

Comment: How do you recommend substituting a function symbol for another? For example, I would like to replace all occurences of function f with function g. For the formula f(a) > f(b), this would result in g(a) > g(b).